# Get Parent of instance

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection, mvvm, viewmodel

I got a container class, `FieldContainer` , this container class is in a `ObservableCollection`, which is in a `ViewModel`. Within the `FieldContainer` are several `Field´s`. These `Field´s` are also in a `ObservableCollection`.

So we got a structure like this:

- ViewModel

  - `ObservableCollection<FieldContainer>`

    - `FieldContainer`

      - `ObservableCollection<Field>`

        - `Field`

My Problem is: Inside my `Field` I want to get the Instance of it´s parent `ViewModel` during runtime. Is it somehow possible to achieve this with reflection? Or some other way?

Comment: Why would you like to do that? It kind-of looks like the XY problem, if you need to 'set' some property on the parent VM, message passing (event aggregation) would probably be a better solution...

Comment: If the `Field` needs to know about the `ViewModel` you are doing something wrong.

Comment: EventAggregation is the main problem i am trying to solve. I fire a event in the `Field`... But if I have multiple Objects using different `FieldContainer`, every object get´s the event fired. So i thought comparing the itemsources is a good idea

Comment: @RobertNagel Then you should either use more specialized messages or every `FieldContainer` should have its own instance of event aggregator - lifetime scoping.